# Hide drupal menu item if cookie is set

Tags: drupal, menu

I'm new to drupal, and I'm trying to hide a menu item or alter it depending on whether a cookie is set.

Anyone who can give some hints as to how you do this?

Comment: How do you place the menu ? as a block ? or as a line in the tpl.php pages ?

Comment: The menu is placed as a block. But it's only a few of the menu items that i want to hide or alter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must define two blocks programmatically and show one depending on whether the cookie is this.